# Flink kafka source stops committing offset after transient failure

Tags: java, apache-kafka, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using `flink` `1.7` with `flink-connector-kafka` version `0.11`.

Flink checkpointing is explicitly turned off and I rely on kafka to commit the offset automatically every 5 seconds. Every now and then I see this error:

```
2019-07-16 08:32:04.273 [JobName] ERROR o.a.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  - [ConsumerName] Offset commit failed on partition topic-name-0 at offset 7591394545: The request timed out.
2019-07-16 08:32:04.273 [JobName] ERROR o.a.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  - [ConsumerName] Offset commit failed on partition topic-name-0 at offset 7591394545: The request timed out.
2019-07-16 08:32:04.310 [JobName] INFO  o.a.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator  - [ConsumerName] Marking the coordinator servername:21000 (id: 2147482313 rack: null) dead
2019-07-16 08:32:04.310 [JobName] INFO  o.a.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator  - [ConsumerName] Marking the coordinator servername:21000 (id: 2147482313 rack: null) dead
2019-07-16 08:32:04.322 [JobName] WARN  o.a.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  - [ConsumerName] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {topic-name-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=7591394751, metadata=''}} failed: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing the latest consumed offsets.
2019-07-16 08:32:04.322 [JobName] WARN  o.a.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  - [ConsumerName] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {topic-name-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=7591394751, metadata=''}} failed: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing the latest consumed offsets.
2019-07-16 08:32:04.337 [JobName] WARN  o.a.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  - [ConsumerName] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {topic-name-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=7591394545, metadata=''}} failed: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing the latest consumed offsets.
2019-07-16 08:32:04.337 [JobName] WARN  o.a.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  - [ConsumerName] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {topic-name-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=7591394545, metadata=''}} failed: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing the latest consumed offsets.
```

When this happen and I check the kafka offset for that group/topic/partition, I can see that they are not auto committed anymore and if I have to restart the job it will replay all the data since the incident.

I there a way for flink to retry the commit of the offset? I would increase the `request.timeout.ms` parameter but it's already at 305'000 ms

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem? We use Flink 1.9 and are experiencing the same error. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't had the issue since we've stop using `flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11` (but instead started using the connector tied to the flink release, `flink-connector-kafka_2.11` version 1.9 in your case). https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html

Comment: Can confirm that after switching to `flink-connector-kafka_2.11` the problem disappeared.